# Can't return focus to the main window after showing dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I create dialog window in MFC using `CWnd::DoModal` function.
The window is instantiated in CWinApp::OnIdle()

```
CPatientFile pf;
pf.DoModal();
```

When the `DoModal` function returns the focus is not returned to the main window.
I tried to set focus manually

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->SetFocus();
```

Also tried to set the main window as foreground or active.

Generally I have touch screen, so when I close the Dialog I need to press the button on the main window to get it work.

So what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Who gets the focus then?

Comment: Have you considered just caching the focused window before `DoModal` and then restoring it after it returns?

Comment: This option was checked too :(

Comment: Can you create a SSCCE that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just check the constructor of CPatientFile. It may be accepting the parent window CWnd *. Pass the main window as the parent.

Like

```
CPatientFile pf(this); //if this code is in main window class itelf
```

or

```
CPatientFile pf(AfxGetMainWnd());
```

**Updated:**

If you have instantiated the dialog from the main window, then the focus will automatically go back to the window when the dialog is closed. I am suspecting that you have instantiated the dialog from the app class itself (CWinApp) after creating the main window. If this is the case then the main window may not get the focus & you must create the dialog from within the main window. Or if you are creating the dialog in a separate thread.

As a work around you can use AfxGetMainWnd()->SetForegroundWindow() or AfxGetMainWnd()->SetActiveWindow(). But first I would try to find the cause of the issue & try to write better code (like suggested in above paragraph).

Comment: I am trying to open the dialog from CWinApp OnIdle. I tried your workaround but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have copy-pasted, the statement is itself incorrect:

```
CPatientFile pf();
```

The next line shouldn't compile at all. Why? Because it is declaring a function named `pf` which returns `CPatientFile`.

If that is correct, may I ask if there is any multithreading involved. Is another thread creating a window? 
How do you check if parent windows has (not) got the focus?

Comment: Oops, you are right. I added this by mistake. Thanks.